# How to I tell a Views Block to only pull Snippets belonging to the same OG as the container page?

Tags: views, organic-groups

I have a few pieces to my existing puzzle:

1. Node Type  **Snippet**
2. View with Block Display called **Snippets Block**
3. A context rule to put the Snippets Block inside a container page

*How to I tell a Views Block to only pull Snippets belonging to the same OG as the container page?*

**To start:**

I've created the following relationship and contextual filter, but the containing page doesn't show the expected node teasers.

[image]
[image]

*Node Type's Fields:*
[image]
([view larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD1hd.png))

*Current View set up:*
[image]
([view larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiRI8.png))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fullerja said, you can use a Contextual Filter but you may also need to define a Relationship first so that the view pulls in the OG that goes with the snippets.

If this page is showing OG content, hopefully it has the OG's slug in the URL. If that's the case then you can use that path for the Contextual filter.

These answers might be helpful for the specific configuration:

- [Organic Groups Views Contextual Filters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121391/organic-groups-views-contextual-filters)
- [How do I display all the nodes in an organic group?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39750/how-do-i-display-all-the-nodes-in-an-organic-group)

Comment: Well, definitely an up vote. I updated my question a bit. Am I getting closer?

Comment: I'm not sure if the contextual filter will get the argument from the context as you have set it. If that doesn't work, try selecting "____ from URL" (options depend on what you are working with). I'm sorry I haven't used OG in a couple of years and I don't a site I can try it on.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a 'Contextual Filter' and use the context of the OG group.

Look at using the group ID as the filter. Once you get into the config for the filter, there should be an option for getting the argument from context.

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/2hD6B.png 
I'm unsure of how to set up such a filter. I'm unsure of which of the available ones to try and why.